# Extract all rows which fall into a certain date period, on an ID basis

Tags: sql-server

I have a task to analyse the first 12 weeks of information relating to each ID.

What i have are two tables;

Contracts and Sales

Contracts has the ID, location and start date of a entity.

Sales has the ID, value and date of the transaction.

What i need is for the Sales table to be restricted to only the sales figures which occur within the range of (Start date) and (Start date + 12 weeks) for each ID

Attached i have included a schema (first time using sqlfiddle!) of the tables for aid.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3c0d5c

In the example of IDs : 701910AIR,702536AIR,700701ARD

Contract Lines are:

```
ID          Start Date  Location
701910AIR   01/08/2016  AIREHGA
702536AIR   01/08/2016  AIREHGA
700701ARD   11/02/2016  ARDRIEI
```

I would be expecting only the follow sales entries to show:

```
Value      Date        ID
 266.05     09/08/2016  701910AIR
 410.25     01/09/2016  701910AIR
 417.10     05/10/2016  701910AIR
 133.00     09/08/2016  702536AIR
 182.35     01/09/2016  702536AIR
 228.80     05/10/2016  702536AIR
 245.91     17/02/2016  700701ARD
 205.57     01/03/2016  700701ARD
 263.65     15/03/2016  700701ARD
 222.20     29/03/2016  700701ARD
 244.55     13/04/2016  700701ARD
 182.50     27/04/2016  700701ARD
```

I apologize in advance, every time i tried to get the date columns into a more recognizable format, the SQLFIDDLE site kept throwing up errors.

Thanks for taking the time to read my question.

Comment: You have tagged this with sql server but your fiddle is for mysql. Which one are you actually using?

Comment: Hi Sean,I had some issues with the schema posting, as mentioned in the post - it's actually Sql server im using.

Comment: Well the other thing is your data in the sqlfiddle doesn't match the data posted here. You stated dates but the fiddle is int. If you can't get sql fiddle to work then post ddl and sample data in your question.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you need function DATEADD(), something like:

```
Select * from sales where
Date > startDate and Date < DATEADD(wk, 12, startDate)
```

Full code in your case:

```
Select s.* from sales s
join Contract c on s.ID = c.ID
where
DDate > c.Start_date and DDate < DATEADD(wk, 12, c.Start_date)
```